# How would I make a turtle object face the same direction as another?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So, for context, I am working on a shooter game using python turtle graphics. I have tried to find something that would work with multiple attempts, but to no avail. For example, I have tried

```
def direction():
 wn.onkey(lambda: shuttle.setheading(90), 'Up')
 wn.onkey(lambda: shuttle.setheading(180), 'Left')
 wn.onkey(lambda: shuttle.setheading(0), 'Right')
 wn.onkey(lambda: shuttle.setheading(270), 'Down')

direction()


bullet.setheading(direction())
```

and

```
if bullet.distance(shuttle) < 15:
28  -    if shuttle.setheading == 90:
29  -      bullet.setheading(90)
30  -    if shuttle.setheading == 180:
31  -      bullet.setheading(180)
32  -    if shuttle.setheading == 0:
33  -      bullet.setheading(0)
34  -    if shuttle.setheading == 270:
35  -      bullet.setheading(270)
```

I apologize for the line numbers, but it seemed like too much of a hassle to remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have 2 turtles: `turtle1` and `turtle2`. To turn `turtle2` to the direction of `turtle1`, use this code:

```py
turtle2.setheading(turtle1.heading())
```

FYI: In your first code snippet, `direction` returns `None`, as it only adds events, so it would not work.

NOTE: I would recommend using tkinter for games, as turtle was created for education use and is very slow.

Comment: This code does not seem to work. python returnds `TypeError: heading() takes exactly 0 positional argument(s) (1 given) on line 26`

Comment: @Thehappysquid, the code is correct.  Reread it carefully and try again.